# How to fix struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes when using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, customtkinter

Output:

```
71944 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_console_script_run())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 194, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 180, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 979, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 901, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/Users/user/AutoClicker/main.spec", line 24, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 576, in __init__
    self.pkg = PKG(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 233, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 284, in assemble
    src_name = checkCache(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/utils.py", line 368, in checkCache
    osxutils.binary_to_target_arch(cachedfile, target_arch, display_name=fnm)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 309, in binary_to_target_arch
    is_fat, archs = get_binary_architectures(filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 285, in get_binary_architectures
    executable = MachO(filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/macholib/MachO.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.load(fp)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/macholib/MachO.py", line 129, in load
    header = struct.unpack(">I", fh.read(4))[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

I'm trying to turn my .py file into an .exe file. I used the following pyinstaller command: `pyinstaller main.py --onefile --windowed --add-binary="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages:lib"`  and it returned `struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes`. Could anyone explain why is this error occurring and the fix to this error?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you adding the lib directory in the add-binary argument?

Comment: I’m trying to make my GUI into an exe file. I used the custom tkinter module. I tried adding the lib directory to add-file argument but it doesn’t work too. If I don’t add it to an add-file or add-binary, causes a json file missing error. Pyinstaller doesn’t automatically include json file so I would have to add it myself.